# How to sort an array keys according to another array values with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

I have a problem in php array. Seems like it won't be very difficult who 
have knowledge on array.

I have two arrays
    Example:
    1st array is:

```
        Array (     
[651] => 12     
[620] => 10     
[681] => 7      
[792] => 6      
[402] => 5)
```

1st array is sorted according to the values with descending order.

2nd array is:

```
    Array (     
[681] => Blue      
[620] => White     
[792] => Red      
[651] => Green        
[402] => Gray)
```

Both array has similar keys.

Now i want an array that should look like this

```
Array (       
[651] => Green        
[620] => White       
[681] => Blue      
[792] => Red      
[402] => Gray)
```

That means 2nd array keys should be sorted according to the value of the 1st array.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). But you shouldn't sort the first array beforehand. If the first array sorted separately you should sync it back by sorting it by keys again (using [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)):

```
// Sync two arrays -- sort by keys.
ksort($array1);
ksort($array2);

// Sort second array accordingly to the first.
array_multisort($array1, SORT_DESC, $array2);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/762802e279baffc955c62b67ff8228f46d2c9d86).

Pay attention that, with this approach, both arrays will be sorted in the end, but you will loose the keys, i.e. arrays will be reindexed.